# Unable to scroll to a tree node

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a `treepanel` and one procedure that expands the tree and selects one particular node. The problem is - I do not know how to scroll to this node, so that it becomes visible. I tried these two methods, I've seen at stackoverflow and other forums:

```
1. 
tree.getSelectionModel().select(node);
tree.getView().focusRow(node);

2.
location.hash=node.data.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/slemmon/P9TkZ/3/.
You may have to use tree.selectPath instead of SelectionModel:

```
tree.selectPath('/Root/path/to/your/node', 'text', '/', function (s, n) {
    var nodeEl = Ext.get(tree.view.getNode(n));
    nodeEl.scrollIntoView(tree.view.el, false, true);
});
```

Found it here: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?251980-scrolling-to-specific-node-in-tree-panel&p=923068#post923068

Answer (score 1):

Use selectPath [method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-method-selectPath)

```
tree.selectPath(node.getPath())
```